# postgresql aggregate by max string length

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a one to many relationship.  In this case, it's a `pipelines` entity that can have many `segments`.  The `segments` entity has a column to list the wells associated with this pipeline.  This column is purely informational, and is only updated from a regulatory source as a comma separated list, so the data type is `text`.

What I want to do is to list all the `pipelines` and show the `segment` column that has the most associated wells. Each well is identified with a standardized land location (text is the same length for each well).  I am also doing other aggregate functions on the `segments`, so my query looks something like this (I have to simplify it because it's pretty large):

```
SELECT pipelines.*, max(segments.associated_wells), min(segments.days_without_production), max(segments.production_water_m3)
FROM pipelines
JOIN segments ON segments.pipeline_id = pipelines.id
GROUP BY pipelines.id
```

This selects the `associated_wells` that has the highest alphabetical value, which makes sense, but is not what I want.

`max(length(segments.associated_wells))` will select the record I want, but only show the length. I need to show the column value.

How can I aggregate based on the string length but show the value?

Here's an example of what I am expecting:

Segment entity:

```
| id | pipeline_id | associated_wells         | days_without_production | production_water_m3 |
|----|-------------|--------------------------|-------------------------|---------------------|
| 1  | 1           | 'location1', 'location2' | 30                      | 2.3                 |
| 2  | 1           | 'location1'              | 15                      | 1.4                 |
| 3  | 2           | 'location1'              | 20                      | 1.8                 |
```

Pipeline entity:

```
| id | name        |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | 'Pipeline1' |
| 2  | 'Pipeline2' |
|    |             |
```

Desired Query Result:

```
| id | name        | associated_wells         | days_without_production | production_water_m3 |
|----|-------------|--------------------------|-------------------------|---------------------|
| 1  | 'Pipeline1' | 'location1', 'location2' | 15                      | 2.3                 |
| 2  | 'Pipeline2' | 'location1'              | 20                      | 1.8                 |
|    |             |                          |                         |                     |
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id) p.*, s.*
FROM pipelines p JOIN
     segments s
     ON s.pipeline_id = p.id
ORDER BY p.id, LENGTH(s.associated_wells) DESC;
```

Comment: not quite, I realized in my question I forgot to add the ```group by``` clause in the query example.  I am doing aggregates on many columns, which is why I included other columns in the example.

Comment: @Sehael . . . You are returning one row per `pipeline.id` in your query, which is what this does.  It seems like what you are asking for.

Comment: take a look at the example I posted.  I want to take the values of some columns from different records.

Answer (score 0):

Keep normalising and verticalise the locations/associated wells, by cross joining with a series of integers, and then group twice:

```
WITH
segment(seg_id,pipeline_id,associated_wells,days_without_production,production_water_m3) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,'location1, location2',30,2.3
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'location1',15,1.4
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,'location1',20,1.8
)
,
pipeline(pipeline_id,name) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Pipeline1'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Pipeline2'
)
,
i(i) AS (
          SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
)
,
location AS (
  SELECT
    seg_id
  , i AS loc_id
  , SPLIT_PART(associated_wells,', ',i) AS location
  FROM segment CROSS JOIN i
  WHERE SPLIT_PART(associated_wells,',' ,i) <>''
)
,
pregroup AS (
  SELECT
    segment.pipeline_id
  , location.location
  , MIN(days_without_production) AS days_without_production
  , MAX(production_water_m3)     AS production_water_m3
  FROM segment
  JOIN pipeline USING(pipeline_id)
  JOIN location USING(seg_id)
  GROUP BY 1,2 
)
SELECT
  pipeline_id
, STRING_AGG(location,',')     AS locations
, MIN(days_without_production) AS days_without_production
, MAX(production_water_m3)     AS production_water_m3
FROM pregroup
GROUP BY 1;
 pipeline_id |      locations      | days_without_production | production_water_m3 
-------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------
           1 | location1,location2 |                      15 |                 2.3
           2 | location1           |                      20 |                 1.8
```